# Space of sections of adjoint varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras, projective-varieties

We will work over the field of complex numbers and we will be consistent with the Grothendieck porjectivization, that is $\mathbb P(\cdot)=\operatorname{Proj}(\operatorname{Sym}(\cdot))$.

Let $X$ be the adjoint variety for a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, that is $X \subset \mathbb P(\mathfrak g)$ is the unique closed $G$-orbit, where $G$ is the adjoint group associated to $\mathfrak g$. We know that, as a $G$-representations,
$$
\mathfrak g=H^0(X, \mathcal O(1)).
$$

Can we describe **explicitly** the space of sections $H^0(X, \mathcal O(m))$ for $m \ge 1$ in terms of $G$-representations involving $\mathfrak g$?

Comment: This is what Borel-Bott-Weil theorem is telling you.

Comment: Ok, for this particular case can we obtain an explicit description?

Comment: Yes, the description given by BBW is absolutely explicit.

Comment: Can you make the explicit argument for $H^0(X, \mathcal O(2))$?

Comment: Of course I can. But it is better for you if you learn the theorem and apply it yourself.